# C/C++ - MinGW - run/compile program with batch

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, g++, mingw

I'm trying to run my program with `MinGW` compiler through batch file. But when I try to launch it, it says nothing.

Here is a code:

```
g++ -o Learning.exe Main.o 
pause
```

When I just opening `.exe` file, it working perfectly. How to fix that?

Comment: The purposed script doesn't actually _run_ your application, it just links it.

Answer (score 3):

GCC is silent if there aren't any issues, errors or warnings.

Do you want to run the actual program you created? Right now you just link it.

To compile and run if there weren't any issues, you can use the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -o learning.exe && learning.exe
pause
```

The part behind `&&` won't be executed, unless there haven't been any error during compilation (return value not being 0).

Comment: Thank you, but did you know, how to connect output to the IDE (Eclipse)? Simply change path to my .bat file?

Comment: Create a new C++ project in Eclipse. That's a lot easier to use than some makefile/batch project.

Comment: Where is makefile/batch project? =/

Comment: When creating a new project, you can make a "makefile project". That won't accept a batch file to build though. Make sure you've got the C++ extensions (CDT) installed (vanilla Eclipse will only allow you to create Java projects).